# Cython: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, anaconda, cython, pyd, cythonize

I compiled my Python code with Cython and got a `.pyd` file. I want to import it so I was advised to put it in my `PYTHONPATH`.

Here it is :

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\spyder\\utils\\site',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\loic\\.ipython']
```

I put my `.pyd` file in `C:\\Users\\loic\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages` and when I tried to import it with Python I got that message:

```
    import maido
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Then I put my `.pyd` file in the same directory as my Python programm and I got the exact same message.

I did some research and I came across that post ([Using cython extension once compiled [under Windows], how to use .pyd's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412764/using-cython-extension-once-compiled-under-windows-how-to-use-pyds)) but it doesn't seem to give me more information.

I am using Python 64 bits with Anaconda 2 because the code I compiled required Python 64 bits (it needed more memory because otherwise the console was quickly saturated in memory).

***Can someone tell me what should I do to make it work with Python 64 bits please ?***

**EDIT:** In case you need it, here is my `setup.py` file

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy as np

setup(name = "maido",
      include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = cythonize("C:\Users\python\Documents\maido\maido_cython.pyx"),
      )
```

Comment: I would try to create a proper python package so that `pip install .` works (maybe with `--user` flag while testing).

Comment: @Lo Are you sure your compiler didn't compile it with a 32bit compiler?  I.e. use the Visual Studio 64bit command prompt then try again

Comment: @Matt I think so, I am using the Anaconda 2 (64 bits) Prompt. You mean that instead of typing `C:\Users\loic\Documents\maido\setup.py build_ext --inplace` I should type `C:\Users\python\Documents\maido\setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=something` or something like it ?

Comment: @Lo What I mean is that if you have a 32bit and 64bit compiler on your system before you Cythonize you should open up the Visual Studio tools command prompt for 64bit before you type the `Cythonize ` command.

Comment: I tried what you said with but it didn't work. I was told that Cython was easy to use but I can't get anything to work. I'll uninstall Anaconda and start again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Loic Cython "easy to use" is a fallacy.  But once you learn it it is very powerful.

Comment: @Matt I succeeded, I made a stupid mistake but my program did not really get any faster. I must have forgot something. As you pointed out Cython is more complicated than it looks.

Comment: Good to hear - I was about to post how to do a fresh install but you beat me to it.  The trick with Cython is you really have to use memoryviews to get direct C++ access between NumPy and Python.  Then you have to learn pointers when passing memoryviews to functions to avoid mem copying.